# change background colour on Android ActionBar

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar, background-color

I have been trying to change the background colour of my **ActionBar** in my app. But it seems to give me some error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

The error I get is on the

```
<item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
```

I just want to change the background of the actionBar to a different colour.

Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you target for minimum API level 11 , you can change ActionBar's background color by defining custom style, as:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And, set "MyTheme" as theme for application / activity.

Comment: Thanks that worked, But could you tell me why my previous wasn't working, because I didn't have the correct file inside of @drawable ?. Also do you know where I can find properties I can change such as "android:background" but list of others?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this online tool to generate a full customized ActionBar
[Here is tool](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to change the color of the `ActionBar` programmatically, just call this line:

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color)));
```

That's also possible via `getSupportActionBar()` (if you're using *ActionBarSherlock*).